# why does push_back vomit a char in the string member in of upcasted object?

Tags: c++, c++11

i am making a rock paper & scissors game. Contains 3 classes as below:

**Human class:-** user puts number of games he wants to play and the choices respectively

**Computer class:-** Plays the same number of game as human but always plays 'ROCK'.

**RandomComputer class :-** Derived class of computer class, but plays Random Moves or choices. 
When i pass any 2 object, a Human and Computer to Refree class it makes a decision by comparing each moves of two players.
Refree Decision method works perfect when **(Human, Computer)** passed BUT unexpected strange output when passed **(Human,RandomComputer)**. 
EXAMPLE:- **user input: 3 R P S

            output when Refree(Human A, Computer B) : Tie Win Lose**
           **output when Refree(Human A, RandomComputer C): Lose ' ' Win**

```
#ifndef _HUMAN_H
#define _HUMAN_H
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Human{
    public:
        Human();
        Human(int number, string game);

    public:
        int h_number;
        string h_game;
};
#endif //_HUM
//=========HUMAN.CPP=====
#include "human.h"
Human::Human(int number, string game){
    h_number = number;
    h_game = game;
}
//========COMPUTER.h=====
#ifndef _COMPUTER_H
#define _COMPUTER_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Computer{
    public:
        Computer();
        Computer(int number);
        int get_c_number();


    public:
        string c_game;
        int c_number;

};
#endif //_COMPUTER_H
//========COMPUTER.CPP=====
#include "computer.h"
Computer::Computer(){

}

Computer::Computer(int number){
    c_number = number;

    for(int i=0; i<c_number; i++)
    {
        c_game.push_back('R');
    }

}
int Computer::get_c_number()
{
    return c_number;
}
//=============RANDOMCOMPUTER.H========
#ifndef _RANDOMCOMPUTER_H
#define _RANDOMCOMPUTER_H
#include "computer.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

class RandomComputer:public Computer{
    public:
        RandomComputer();
        RandomComputer(int number);



    private:
        static const char r_games[3];

};
#endif //_RANDOMCOMPUTER_H
//===============RANDOMCOMPUTER.CPP=========
#include "randomcomputer.h"
const char RandomComputer::r_games[3]= {'R','P','S'};
RandomComputer::RandomComputer(){}
RandomComputer::RandomComputer(int number){
    c_number = number;
    srand ( time(NULL) );
    for(int i=0; i<c_number; i++)
    {

        int RandIndex = rand() % 3;
        c_game.push_back(r_games[RandIndex]);
    }

}
//==============REFREE.H======
#ifndef _REFREE_H
#define _REFREE_H
#include "computer.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "human.h"
#include "randomcomputer.h"
using namespace std;
class Refree{
    public:
    Refree();
        Refree (Human h_temp, Computer c_temp);
        void decision();
        Human *x;
        Computer *y;

    private:
        int r_number;
        string output;
};
#endif //_REFREE_H
//============REFREE.CPP========
#include "refree.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
Refree::Refree(){}

Refree::Refree (Human h_temp, Computer c_temp){
    x = &h_temp;
    y = &c_temp;

    r_number = x->h_number;


    cout<<"HUMAN CHOICES: "<<x->h_game<<" COMPUTER CHOICES: "<<y->c_game<<endl;
}


void Refree::decision(){
    for(int i =0; i<r_number; i++){
            cout<<x->h_game[i]<<"-----------------------"<<y->c_game[i]<<endl;
    }
    for(int j =0; j<r_number; j++)
        {
        cout<<x->h_game[j]<<"---COMPARING WITH---"<<y->c_game[j]<<endl;

        if(x->h_game[j] == 'R')
        {
            if(y->c_game[j] == 'P')
            {
                output.push_back('L');
                output.push_back(' ');
            }
            else if(y->c_game[j]=='S')
            {
                output.push_back('W');
                output.push_back(' ');
            }
            else if(y->c_game[j]=='R')
            {
                output.push_back('T');
                output.push_back(' ');
            }
        }
        else if(x->h_game[j] == 'P')
        {
            if(y->c_game[j] == 'P')
            {
                output.push_back('T');
                output.push_back(' ');
            }
            else if(y->c_game[j]=='S')
            {
                output.push_back('L');
                output.push_back(' ');
            }
            else if(y->c_game[j]=='R')
            {
                output.push_back('W');
                output.push_back(' ');
            }
        }

        else if(x->h_game[j] == 'S')
        {
            if(y->c_game[j] == 'P')
            {
                output.push_back('W');
                output.push_back(' ');
            }
            else if(y->c_game[j]=='S')
            {
                output.push_back('T');
                output.push_back(' ');
            }
            else if(y->c_game[j]=='R')
            {
                output.push_back('L');
                output.push_back(' ');
            }
        }

}//forrr looop
    size_t endpos = output.find_last_not_of(" \t");
    if( string::npos != endpos )
    {
        output = output.substr( 0, endpos+1 );
    }
    cout<<output<<endl;
    output.clear();
}
//============================MAIN.CPP====================
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include "human.h"
#include "computer.h"
#include "refree.h"
#include "randomcomputer.h"


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string user_input;
    getline(cin, user_input);
    //converting the numbers in the string to int.
    int number_of_games = atoi(user_input.c_str());
    //remove the digits and the spaces
    user_input.erase(remove_if(user_input.begin(), user_input.end(), ::isdigit), user_input.end());
    user_input.erase(remove_if(user_input.begin(), user_input.end(), ::isspace), user_input.end());

    Human player_1(number_of_games, user_input); //HUMAN PLAYER OBJECT
    Computer computer_1(number_of_games); // COMPUTER PLAYER TAKES ONLY innt number because it will always play ROCK in this class

    Refree refree_1(player_1, computer_1);
    refree_1.decision();

    RandomComputer random_computer(number_of_games);
    cout<<"HERE IS THE RANDOM CHOICES FROM COMPUTER AI: "<<random_computer.c_game<<endl; // make random choices instead of only ROCKS.
    Refree refree_2(player_1, random_computer);
    refree_2.decision();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The title alone for this question just makes me want to uptick it.

Comment: Then I get to the code and want to downvote it a million times. Where is your [minimal testcase](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: `x = &h_temp;  y = &c_temp;` - think hard about the lifetime of the objects residing at those addresses you're stowing away.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thank you craig.. got you point... they just resided in the constructor and were destroyed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are copying your Human and Computer object when passing them to the Referee:

```
Refree::Refree (Human h_temp, Computer c_temp){
```

You should use either const references or pointers here.

Comment: u mean like: Human *player = new Human(Int, String);
 and pass this pointer to the Refree object?

Comment: As @WhozCraig already stated your problem is the life time of the objects.

Currently you are doing this:

+ Create player_1 on stack,
+ Create computer (or randomized_computer) on stack,
+ Pass them to the constructor of refugee (creates copy) &  Save pointers **of the copies** in members.

So yes, you could either create the your objects on stack with new and just pass the pointers to the refugee OR you could pass the reference of the objects to the refugee and save these references as members.

Don't forget to delete objects created with new.

Comment: Just to make things clear: You problem is that the pointers go to the copies (which aren't initialized correctly at this point) which will be destroyed as soon as you leave the constructor for the Refugee.

Comment: Got it. well i was working with the copies and pointers were pointing to the copies. But how come it always worked when i passed Refree(Human, Computer), it was a copy as well? Thank you @Simon.

Comment: You were just lucky that the memory was not written over at the time of execution.

Comment: cool cool.. Knowledgee +1.. thank you simon... great  explanation.